# How to add iAds across multiple UITableaview Controllers

Tags: uiviewcontroller, uitableview, iad

I am looking for a tutorial on how to add an iAd view fixed within a UInavigationController that is constant across the hierarchy rather than a different instance for each one.

Thanks guys

Answer (score 0):

I found the Apple doc to be actually the best entry - http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/userexperience/Conceptual/iAd_Guide/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009881. For the purpose you describe the best example is the navigation example in the demo project : http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/iAdSuite/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40010198. It shows how to use always the same instance of the banner through the navigation views.